# Can you use "any" with other tenses?

Tags: tense, determiners, subjects, any

I have looked through many websites and know that when "any" is used as a determiner, it can be used with countable or uncountable nouns. I also read in my textbook that when "any" is used as part of the subject clause, it suggests restrictedness.

And so my question are,

1. If "any" is used as a determiner in the subject clause, can it be used with different verb tenses, like perfect or perfect continuous?
2. Why is example sentence #1 okay, but not sentences #2 and #3?

For example:

#1 Any of your questions CAN BE ASKED. (sentence okay)

#2 *Any of your questions HAVE BEEN ASKED. (present perfect 3rd person plural tense sentence not okay)

#3 *Any of your questions HAS BEEN ASKED. (present perfect 3rd person singular tense sentence not okay)

Comment: Number 2 would work if you said something like "I don't know if any of your questions HAVE BEEN ASKED." Any implies plural, though, which is why 3 won't work.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* has **nothing to do with the verb**, so tense is irrelevant. All of the following are acceptable, past present and future:

- She didn't find any of the coins.
- We don't find any problem with your work.
- I won't have any time tomorrow to do that.

It is the *logic* of sentences 2 and 3 that are at fault. Since they're in the past, it is not any one question, but *all* of the questions that have been asked. In addition, #3 uses the wrong helper verb.